# "Harmonic analysis" comment

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I would like to start studying *Fourier and Harmonic analysis* (from the analytic point of view). What I would like to ask is how suitable *Stein's book "Harmonic analysis : real-variable methods, orthogonality, and oscillatory integrals"* is as a guiding reference.

Is it a biblic text suitable just as a reference book (like Hartshorne for Algebraic Geometry) or can it be used as an instructive book? Does it have to be supplemented by some excescises (like by the Grafakos's books?). Thank you for your comments!

Comment: May I ask what's your background on Fourier analysis?

Comment: Nothing more than basic tools like Fourier transform and some Fourier series in Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Stein's book is a monograph rather than a textbook. It is a good idea to read Stein's monograph along with supplementary textbooks. For instance, Grafakos' two books from GTM series could be helpful for maximal functions, Hardy and BMO spaces. You may find Groechenig's book helpful for PDO's. I'd be glad to exchange ideas & additional references in this medium as you advance through Stein's book.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! Sure, I’ll be happy to do so as soon as I start my Fourier-Harmonic Analysis plan!

Comment: If you are first to read harmonic analysis stuff, I would recommend Stein's singular integral and Grafakos at the same time. You may get lost when you read Grafakos book only. I would suggest read Stein's singular integral and refer Grafakos if you have some trouble to calculate something.

Comment: Thank you Will! By the way, how would compare Stein’s “Singular integrals” with respect to Stein’s “Harmonic analysis […]”? Would you consider one as more “lecture notes” than the other (which may be more monograph)?